# scraping of all ios apps for testing

Tags: python, ios, screen-scraping, ipa

i'm wondering how i could download all ios apps (.ipa files). i want to make a script (prefered: python). i know how to program but i have no clue how to download the apps!

apple provides a multi-gb list of all metadata, which is useful, but i can not download the apps itself without using itunes because there are no http links. automatization of the itunes gui would be a very crappy way of doing it. do you know how i could download all of them?

the only other way, which came to my mind was using unofficial ios app stores which provide http links, but i want to download them from the offical store.

sincerly trashy

Comment: There is no way to do this (by design) and it is against Apple's TOS to attempt to do so.

Comment: Even of this was possible, were you ready to pay for all the paid ones? ;)